# How to mark every 3rd post

Tags: posts, count, post-class

I'm working on a WordPress site for my band and I'd like to mark every 3rd post on our blog page to have a special class applied to it, anybody have any pointers on how to achieve this? Any help is very very appreciated, thanks! rock n roll.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My approach. No extra function, no filter. :)

```
<?php $GLOBALS['wpdb']->current_post = 0; ?>
<div <?php post_class( 0 === ++$GLOBALS['wpdb']->current_post % 3 ? 'third' : '' ); ?>>
```

Alternative:

```
<div <?php post_class( 0 === ++$GLOBALS['wpdb']->wpse_post_counter % 3 ? 'third' : '' ); ?>>
```

Comment: this killed it @toscho! turns out this one worked the best since im using this on a category page and a fn was styling posts everywhere. thanks man, +1. i dont think i have the privs to +1 yet officially.

Comment: Doesn't this actually affect the Globals value (due to the pre-increment operator) and potentially screw up something else that might be depending on the current_post count property? I mean, the likelihood is slim, right, but wouldn't it be safer to just do ( 0 === ( $GLOBALS['wpdb']->current_post + 1 ) % 3 ? 'third' : '' ) ?

Comment: @TomAuger For some not so obvious reason it doesn’t seem to have any side effect. But from a perspective of elegance – you are right. I added a better example. :)

Comment: `Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$current_post in`

Answer (score 9):

*As an addition to @helgathevikings answer*

#### Use the post_class() fn without polluting the global namespace

1. Using `static` variables inside a class allows the same behavior as having global variables: They stay in place and don't change, unless you don't alter them.
2. Even better (as @Milo suggested in the comments), take the current post from the DB class.

The Example:

```
function wpse44845_add_special_post_class( $classes )
{
    // Thanks to @Milo and @TomAuger for the heads-up in the comments
    0 === $GLOBALS['wpdb']->current_post %3 AND $classes[] = 'YOUR CLASS';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class','wpse44845_add_special_post_class' );
```

### Update

We could utilize the `current_post` property of the global `$wp_query` object. Let's  use an *anonymous* function, with the `use` keyword, to pass on the global `$wp_query` by reference (*PHP 5.3+*):

```
add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes ) use ( &$wp_query )
{
    0 === $wp_query->current_post %3 AND $classes[] = 'YOUR CLASS';

    return $classes;
} );
```

Further on, we could restrict it to the *main loop* with a [`in_the_loop()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162787/26350) conditional check.

Comment: i like it.  don't quite understand static variables.  one more thing to learn today!

Comment: why not just use `$wpdb->current_post`?

Comment: @Milo Good catch +1

Comment: thank you dudes so much, really appreciate the help! adding this in right now!

Comment: ah this function is badass @kaiser and beautifully simple! turns out i needed something just for a category page. this shall save me later on in life my friend, thanks for learning me something new. +11!

Comment: @Zoran Btw: You should mark toschos Code as the solution. Most elegant.

Comment: Do you need to globalize $wpdb inside your function?

Comment: @TomAuger Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

if your theme uses post_class() to generate post classes you could try.  i'm not 100% sure how it will handle pagination b/c i don't have enough posts on my local install to test it out

```
add_filter('post_class','wpa_44845');

global $current_count;

$current_count = 1;

 function wpa_44845( $classes ){

    global $current_count;

    if ($current_count %3 == 0 ) $classes[] = 'special-class';

    $current_count++;

    return $classes;

 }
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I guess you could use a `static` var instead of a `global` to keep the namespace clean. Anyway: +1.

Comment: you mean change both global $current_count to static $current_count?  doesn't seem to do anything when i test it. not familiar enough w/ variable scope, though i agree it is better to not pollute the namespace if you can.

Comment: See the [answer below](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44908/385)

Comment: you could also use `$wpdb->current_post` without having to create another variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 0;
if ( have_posts ) :
while( have_posts ) :
    the_post();

    $class = 'class="BASIC-CLASS';
    if ( 0 === ( $i % 3 ) )
        $class .= 'YOUR-SPECIAL-CLASS';
    $class .= '"';

    echo "<div {$class}>";
        // do stuff
    echo '</div>';

    $i++;
endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are also ways to do this with CSS and javascript.

With CSS3 you target every third post with an nth-child selector.

```
article.post:nth-child(3n+0)
{
    background-color: #777;
}
```

Or with jQuery, you could add the CSS class using the same technique.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "article.post:nth-child(3n+0)" ).addClass("custom-class");
});
```