# Add class to every other posts using get_posts

Tags: php, loop, get-posts

I am currently using this little loop to display a list of posts using the "events" custom post type

```
<?php global $post; // required
    $args = array('post_type' => 'events');
    $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>


<ul><li class="post">Content goes here</li></ul>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I want to do is add a class to every other list item so that I can style them alternatively (One white, one black, one white, one black, for example)

I've done this before with a standard loop but I'm only just converting over to get_posts so I'm a bit stuck.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mark every 3rd post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post)

Comment: Take a look at this ↑ Q. It's not every third, but you can just exchange `3` with `2`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add an alternating class to every other post in the list. In particular, (in your style.css) style the list elements `<li>` in one particular way, and then over-ride that style for list elements of a particular class `<li class='my-alternate-class'>`. The class `my-alternate-cass` will applied to every other list element:

```
<?php global $post;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'events');
    $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
    if($custom_posts):?>
         <ul>;
         <?php foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
              <?php $class = (empty($class) ? "class='my-alternate-class'" : "");?>
              <li <?php echo $class;?>>Content goes here</li>
         </ul>;
         <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    //Remember to wp_reset_postdata() afterwards
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

*Please note this untested.*

I've also added [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata/) as otherwise your site might break.

Answer (score 0):

I know a CSS3 solution:

```
li {background: #000;}
li:nth-child(odd) {background: #fff;}
```

The same can be achieved with jQuery, where  `#eventlist` is the id of your unordered list:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#eventlist li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alternate');
});
```

And then: `.alternate {background: #fff;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0; // Reset counter before the loop
$thenumber = ( $counter%2 ) + 1; // Set counter reset (every 2nd count in this example)
$counter++; // Increment number

echo $thenumber; // Echoes 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 and so on...
```

This could be used like this:

```
<li class="post postCount<?php echo $thenumber; ?>">Content goes here</li>
```

so that you get

```
<li class="post postCount1"></li>
<li class="post postCount2"></li>
<li class="post postCount1"></li>
```

Hope this works!

(by the way, you might want to move the `<ul>` tags outside the loop, so that you have only one list with the list items looping inside)