# Customise the appearance of 4 specific post ID's within the loop?

Tags: posts, loop

I am using Isotope and I currently have each post rendering as a box on my homepage. I am currently trying to edit my (working) query that currently displays all posts with the category slug of 'static'. Within that query i'd like to target 4 specific post ID's and customise the appearance of each of those 4 posts. So each of those 4 posts will have different content to one another. How can I adjust this working loop so that I can add/remove content for 4 different post ID's?

Just to note as well, in my template file, I have another query below this query that displays posts from 6 other categories. The code is the same but I've just changed a link position. I hope that all makes sense!

```
<?php
            // Query just the category static and make the link manually editable through the 'URL' custom field
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args= array(
                'category_name' => 'static',
                'paged' => $paged
            );
            query_posts($args);
            if( have_posts() ) :?>

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

              <?php foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) echo '<div class="module ' . $cat->slug . '" data-category="' . $cat->slug . '" >'; ?>

                  <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'URL', true); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                  <div class="active">
                        <div class="hover"></div>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                  </div>

                  <h1><?php the_title(); ?> <span>/ Explode here</span></h1>
                  <?php
                  // Call in the contents of a custom field called Excerpt and if custom field in admin panel is empty don't display <p> tags otherwise wrap contents in <p> tags
                  $excerpt=get_post_meta($post->ID,'Excerpt',true);
                  if($excerpt != '') {
                  echo '<p>'. $excerpt .'</p>';
                  } else {
                  echo ' ';
                  }
                  ?>
                  <p class="date"><!-- for sorting boxes, use post id or date format must be yyyyMMdd--><?php the_time('Ydm') ?></p>
                 </a>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?> 
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging I came up with this IF statement which solves my problem:

```
<?php 
                    $flickr_large = 64;
                    $flickr_small = 113;
                    $join = 117;
                    $twtrfeed = 120;
                    if ( $post->ID == $flickr_large ) :  ?>

                            <ul id="cycle"></ul>

                        <?php elseif ( $post->ID == $flickr_small ) : ?>

                            <div id="flickr-wrap"></div>

                        <?php elseif ( $post->ID == $join ) : ?>

                            <p>Join us box - form here?</p>

                        <?php elseif ( $post->ID == $twtrfeed ) : ?>

                            <p>This where the twitter feed will go</p>

                        <?php else : ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'URL', true); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

                            <div class="active">
                               <div class="hover"></div>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) on your post-container element.

```
// Example:
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('special-class-name'); ?>>
```

You can the target your specific posts with `#post-IDNR` in your css/js files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Surely that only allows me to control style? How would I give each box different content though? For example I need to add a flickr slideshow in one of the boxes and a contact form in another?

Comment: You wrote _customise the appearance_ and not _the content_... Take a look at my latest answers: "how to style every 3rd post" or similar.

Comment: I did mention different content, "So each of those 4 posts will have different content to one another." Regarding your latest answers, where might I find this?

Comment: [Here it is](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post/44908#44908). Oh, and yes, it seems I overread that.