# Style every four posts differently

Tags: loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mark every 3rd post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post)

Is it possible to style every four posts differently?
I mean something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div>1st post</div>
<div>2nd post</div>
<div>3rd post</div>
</div>
<div class="row>
<div>4th post</div>
</div>
...Repeat
```

I'm using [cssgrid](http://cssgrid.net/), so it would be great if I could experiment more with that.. :)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post

Answer (score 1):

Standard Loop:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>    
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Loop checking for 4th post:

```
<?php $i = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $i++; ?>        
    <?php if(!$i%4): get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() . '-4th' ); ?>
    <?php else: get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```