# How to repeat a loop after 4 posts

Tags: posts, loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mark every 3rd post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post)
>   [Style every four posts differently](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66742/style-every-four-posts-differently)

Is it possible to repeat this loop after four posts? 
(post 5 = post 1 css, post 6 = post 2 css, etc..)

```
<?php
if (have_posts()):

   while (have_posts()) :

      the_post();

      $count++;

      if ($count == 1) : ?>

         <div>Styled post 1</div>

      <?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>    

         <div>Styled post 2</div>

      <?php elseif ($count == 3) : ?>

         <div>Styled post 3</div>

      <?php elseif ($count == 4) : ?>  

         <div>Styled post 4</div>

      <?php else : ?>

      <?php endif;

   endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're only using the counter to decide what style to use, the easiest way to achieve what you want would be to reset the $count variable once it gets to 4.

```
<?php elseif ($count == 4) : ?>  

    <div>Styled post 4</div>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>

<?php else : ?>
```