# Alternating post layout

Tags: posts, loop

I am trying to create a layout with two different divs alternating vertically.
For example the even has to be: picture + content; and the odd has to be: content + picture.

Here is my code, at the moment it prints every post doubled, once per div:

```
<div id="content">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="leftcontent_1">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
    </div>

    <div id="rightcontent_1">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>      
    <div class="clear"></div>

<?php else : ?>

<div id="rightcontent_2">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
    </div>

    <div id="leftcontent_2">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>      
    <div class="clear"></div>

<?php endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Any hint on how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post)?

Comment: I know that it doesn't make sense, my original was written in this way but not working at all: `$i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post();`

In this way it is working a 50%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minimal necessary correction - move `the_post();` to before the `if(($i%2 == 0) :`

for instance:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) :  ?>
```

Comment: Damn, I was so near the solution....thank you this fixed my problem. Thank you very much answer accepted.

Comment: Don't forget to `unset` the var at the end. Else you're left with a global of `$i` and a lot of possible unexpected results...

Answer (score 1):

### Built into the query

Alternating post styles (or classes) are not that hard. The `$wp_query` object has a `current_post` property, that you can build upon. Simply do some math with it.

### Example

A very basic example that checks if we got an even or odd post.

```
global $wp_query;
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();
        if ( 0 === $wp_query->current_post %2 )
        {
            // do stuff for even posts

            // Jump to next post in the loop
            continue;
        }
        // do stuff for odd posts
    }
}
```