# Multi row post list

Tags: posts, query-posts, duplicates, post-duplication

I'm trying to create a 'two posts per row grid'.
Here is the template i made:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span2">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 

  </div>
  <div class="span4 pull-left">
        <?php query_posts('category_name=portfolio&posts_per_page=100');  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?> 

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;
 ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p><?php _e('Sorry, this page does not exist.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
 <div class="span4 pull-right">
        <?php query_posts('category_name=portfolio&posts_per_page=100');  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?> 
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;
 ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p><?php _e('Sorry, this page does not exist.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
```

Something is wrong, cause all posts are visible in both divs, how do I tell wordpress to only add odd posts to the first div and even posts to the second?

Comment: Have you seen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post?

Comment: @toscho Yes, but I don't think they are trying to do the same thing? They're 'just' trying to style every 3rd post with a special class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with using this code:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=Menucard'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="span4 post move pull-left">
        <?php
            //echo post here
            the_content();
        ?>

    </div> <!-- close .post div -->

    <?php
        $counter++;
        if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
        }
    ?>
```