# the_content and is_main_query

Tags: filters, conditional-tags, the-content

I am filtering the content with the `the_content` filter. Everything works perfect, excerpt that my changes are applied to custom queries as well. My changes appear in the sidebar as well if the widget uses a custom query

To counter that, I'm using `is_main_query()` to target the main query only, but it is not working. Changes are simply still applied to all queries through out. What is funny though, all other conditional checks like `is_single()` and `is_category()` is working if I target specific pages, except that all changes affect any other custom query on that page, whether I use `is_main_query()` or not

Am I missing something here. How do I apply my changes to the main query only using the `the_content` filter

```
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_content');

function custom_content($content){

    if(is_main_query()){ // << THIS IS NOT WORKING
        // My custom content that I add to the_content()    
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be honest, the function [`in_the_loop()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_the_loop/) is what you are looking for:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_content' );

function custom_content( $content ) {
    if ( in_the_loop() ) {
        // My custom content that I add to the_content()    
    }
    return $content;
}
```

What `in_the_loop` does is to check if global for `$wp_query` (that is the main query object) of the current post is `-1 < $current_post < $post_count`.

That happens when the main query is looping, because before loop starts, current post is -1, and after loop ends, current post is reset to -1 again.

So, if `in_the_loop()` is true, it means that the main query object is looping, which is what you need in this case (and is the same result of adding the action on `loop_start` and removing on `loop_end`, like the answer @ialocin wrote; in fact it works for the same reason, and got my +1).

Benefit of @ialocin's approach is when you want to target a different query object than main one, because `in_the_loop()` only works for main query.

Comment: In none of my site searches or online searched did I come across this. A hidden gem that works. Every solution uses `is_main_query`, really think no one tested this thoroughly. Thank you for your input, really appreciated

Comment: @PieterGoosen Glad it works. That is a very old function, coming straight from times when `is_main_query` was not a thing.

Comment: You see, this is where I missed it, I'm not an old timer :-), joined Wordpress in 3.3.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's to early on sunday morning for me, but I don't quite get how `in_the_loop` is supposed to check for the same thing as `is_main_query`. @PieterGoosen

Comment: @G.M. would you mind adding this to your answer. This is useful info to others that might stumble upon this answer. Most people, like me, don't read comments :-)

Comment: Thanks, I just really should have drank my tea first :) I see it now - it is indeed quite practical. Although logically it actually kind of sucks, because it probably should be named `in_The_Loop` as it is a main query only check - at least the function is. So if you want to check, not the main query but in the loop, you're back to square one - that wasn't the question though :)

Comment: @PieterGoosen done :)

Comment: @ialocin yes, absolutely. Updated answer with some additional info.

Answer (score 7):

This is merely an addition to @Otto's answer. Just to make it a little bit better understandable. Basically what @Otto is saying, you have to reverse the logic, that means: if you can reliably determine the main query, then you can add - and remove - your hooking into the `the_content` filter.

For example the main query can reliably be recognized at the `pre_get_posts` action, so this would work:

```
function wpse162747_the_content_filter_callback( $content ) {
    return $content . 'with something appended';
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse162747_pre_get_posts_callback' );
function wpse162747_pre_get_posts_callback( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse162747_the_content_filter_callback' );
    }
}
```

As you are supposed to remove the filter when it is not longer needed, I'm thinking the `loop_end` action should be a good place for that and as its counterpart we can use `loop_start`. Which would look like this:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse162747_loop_start_callback' );
function wpse162747_loop_start_callback( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse162747_the_content_filter_callback' );
    }
}

add_action( 'loop_end', 'wpse162747_loop_end_callback' );
function wpse162747_loop_end_callback( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse162747_the_content_filter_callback' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Will test this tommorow. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: My pleasure as always @PieterGoosen No hurry, but do it, because I haven't - at least not sufficient enough.

Comment: What if a shortcode is in use within the_content() and the shortcode starts another query that calling the_content(), reset the current post object and the loop continues? All filter will apply. Quite tricky here, not saved by the bell in_the_loop() ... Thats why I suggest, to always remove unique filters as soon as they done, as approached by @Nicolai

Answer (score 5):

You're using `is_main_query()` incorrectly. The global is_main_query() function returns true unless the global $wp_query variable has been redefined.

There is probably no 100% reliable way to tell, from inside a the_content filter, whether or not the current Loop you're in is the main query or not. The content filter just filters content. It doesn't have any form of ability to know what loop it is being used for.

Instead, you should add your filter when you need it, then remove it when you don't.

Comment: It is actually a let-down that there is no straighforward means to target the main query with `the_content` filter

Comment: Well, that really is not surprising though. Like any other filter, it just filters things. It doesn't know the context surrounding when it is being called. It might not even be called from inside a proper Loop. No way for it to tell.