# the_content and wp_link_pages

Tags: loop, hooks, the-content, wp-link-pages

Many plugins seem to be adding a filter/action hook to `the_content` to display related posts, advertisements and such. The problem is I these appear *before* the post pagination so it the pagination is pushed down below.

Is it possible to display the post pagination right after the content? It appears `wp_link_pages` can only be used inside the loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you have:

```
the_content();
wp_link_pages();
```

in your theme file. So you can instead try the following (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
/**
 * Append the wp_link_pages to the content.
 */
! is_admin() && add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content )
{
    if( in_the_loop() ) 
    {
        $args = [ 'echo' => false ];        // <-- Adjust the arguments to your needs!
        $content .= wp_link_pages( $args );
    }
    return $content;
}, 10 );                                    // <-- Adjust the priority to your needs!
```

and then adjust the *arguments* and *priority* to your needs. Notice the `echo` parameter, it's set to false, because we need to return the output. You then have to remove `wp_link_pages()` from your (child) theme file.

### Update:

If we don't want to remove the extra `wp_link_pages()` by hand, we can use the `wp_link_pages` filter to only display the output, within our `the_content` filter callback:

```
/**
 * Append the wp_link_pages to the content.
 */
! is_admin() && add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content )
{
    if( in_the_loop() ) 
    {
        $args = [ 'echo' => false, '_show' => true ];  // <-- Adjust the arguments to your needs!
        $content .= wp_link_pages( $args );
    }
    return $content;
}, 10 );                                              // <-- Adjust the priority to your needs!

/**
 * Only display wp_link_pages() output when the '_show' argument is true.
 */
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages', function( $output, $args )
{
    return ! isset( $args['_show'] ) || ! wp_validate_boolean( $args['_show'] ) ? '' : $output;
}, 10, 2 );
```

where we've introduced the extra `_show` argument for this purpose.

Comment: Wow, it works! Does that mean the hook binded to `the_content` is inside The Loop?

Comment: great, you can add the `in_the_loop()` condition, check out this [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162747/the-content-and-is-main-query) by Pieter Goosen & the answer by gmazzap. @PineappleUndertheSea

Comment: it was a good question + answers, that helped many for sure ;-) @PieterGoosen