# Automatically insert php function into post $the_content

Tags: functions, loop, the-content, wp-insert-post, wp-update-post

I am trying to have 2 php functions automatically inserted in every post for my CPT. The problem I am having is that even though I've found a way to add text, Im not sure how to add the php functions cause with the code I have it adds it as regular text to the post.

This is what I have in my functions file ---

```
    add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content', 10, 2 );

    function my_editor_content( $content, $post ) {

        switch( $post->post_type ) {
            case 'property':
 $content = "<div>";
                $content . "<?php if ( class_exists( 'MRP_Multi_Rating_API' ) ) {
        MRP_Multi_Rating_API::display_rating_result( array(
                'rating_item_ids' => 2,
                'show_count' => false,
                'result_type' => 'value_rt',
    'no_rating_results_text' => 'Not Rated'
        ) ); } ?><?php if ( class_exists( 'MRP_Multi_Rating_API' ) ) {
        MRP_Multi_Rating_API::display_rating_result( array(
                'rating_item_ids' => 5,
                'show_count' => false,
                'result_type' => 'overall_rt',
    'no_rating_results_text' => 'Not Rated'
        ) );
    } ?>";
 $content = "</div>";
            break;
            default:
                $content = "your default content";
            break;
        }

        return $content;
    }
```

How can I fix this so my functions work and is it possible to make it add to every post not just the new ones created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to add php functionality inside the content area. Or, [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to capture the output and append to the [$content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/default_content/) you are returning.

---

> The ["the_content"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter is used to filter the content of the post after it is retrieved from the database and before it is printed to the screen.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );

function my_the_content_filter($content) {

    $post = $GLOBALS['post'];

    ob_start();

    switch($post->post_type) {
        case 'property':
            if(class_exists('MRP_Multi_Rating_API')) {
                MRP_Multi_Rating_API::display_rating_result(array(
                                                                'rating_item_ids'        => 2,
                                                                'show_count'             => false,
                                                                'result_type'            => 'value_rt',
                                                                'no_rating_results_text' => 'Not Rated',
                                                            ));

                MRP_Multi_Rating_API::display_rating_result(array(
                                                                'rating_item_ids'        => 5,
                                                                'show_count'             => false,
                                                                'result_type'            => 'overall_rt',
                                                                'no_rating_results_text' => 'Not Rated',
                                                            ));
            }
            break;
    }

    $extra = ob_get_clean();

    if( ! empty($extra)) {
        return "<div>" . $content . $extra . "</div>";
    }

    return $content;
}
```

---

If you want to just insert stuff into content use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on the $post.

```
$post = get_post(37);

// Update post 37
$my_post = array(
    'ID'           => $post->ID,
    'post_content' => str_replace('round hole', 'square peg' . ' round hole', $post->post_content),
);

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post($my_post);
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way so that is actually inserted within $content? It seems to append it after the_content, but because of the wordpress search function only searches the_title and the_content, I need the functions to be in the_content so I can be able to search for it from the search form.

Comment: There are other ways to insert things into the content. And, as with search, you'll need to create another question for that because it's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: `$post = get_post($ID);

// Update post 37
$my_post = array(
    'ID'           => $post->ID,
    'post_content' => str_replace('round hole', 'square peg' . ' round hole', $post->post_content),
);

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post($my_post);` Like this? How do I add the functions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you want to use `the_content` filter instead of the `default_content` filter (already mentioned by @jgraup) because what happens if the generated HTML changes? Then you're stuck with it in your content. It's better to add it dynamically. Here's one suggestion:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content)
{
    if( ! in_the_loop() )
        return $content;

    if( 'property' !== get_post_type() )
        return $content;

    $args = [
        'rating_item_ids'           =>  2,
        'show_count'                => false,
        'result_type'               => 'value_rt',
        'no_rating_results_text'    => 'Not Rated',
        'echo'                      => 0,
    ];

    if ( class_exists( 'MRP_Multi_Rating_API' ) ) 
    {
        $content .= MRP_Multi_Rating_API::display_rating_result( $args ); 

        // Modify arguments for the second run
        $args['rating_item_ids'] = 5;
        $args['result_type']     = 'overall_rt';

        $content .= MRP_Multi_Rating_API::display_rating_result( $args ); 
    }

    return $content;
} );
```

Notice that we use the [`in_the_loop`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162787/26350) check (here I link to the question by @PieterGoosen and the answer by @gmazzap), because I assume you don't want this added to every content part of your site.

You also don't need to check twice for the existince of the same class.

Note that this has one big assumption, namely the `echo` attribute ;-)

Comment: He wants to insert the output so it becomes searchable by the default WP search... which means both methods are a bust. If it's searchable then you would already have the values / display rendered in advance.

Comment: @jgraup Yeah I need the text to be present within the_content. This is the only use I make of "the_content" cause everything else I hard coded within my single.php files. So there's all type of stuff being displayed/rendered within my posts, but it doesnt come from the_content so I am unable to search for it. The functions echo text for ratings such as "decent". When searching that word though, nothing comes up.

Comment: @jgraup both of your codes work but it's not going into the_content like I need, it is being added after. If I do it with plain text then it seems to work and even shows up on the post edit. Im not sure how to workaround this with functions though.

Comment: If I asked you how to insert '123' into 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', how would you answer that?

Comment: I see, what information do you need from the generated HTML code and where is that data stored in the database (custom table?) Maybe you could do some extra joins for the search? @mygm26 That might be better served with a, new question, as suggested by jgraup.

Comment: jgraup I dont know if you trying to be funny or what. @birgire The functions generate just text. Im not sure where the data is stored in the DB lol if I did my question would probably be different. I just know I use those functions to echo out the text I need.

Comment: at least it sounds problematic to me to have the ratings hardcoded into the post content - what happens when the ratings change? So that's why I would avoid that if possible  ;-) PHPMyAdmin should show you how it's stored @mygm26

Comment: @birgire Ok I checked PHPMyAdmin and it looks like the values I need is coming from here -- SELECT * 
FROM  `tr_mrp_rating_result` 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: @birgire any ideas?

Comment: @birgire Or instead, is it possible to use the above code to store it in a custom field instead of $content?