# check if FILTER("the_content") is being executed in `the_post()`

Tags: filters

I want to use

```
add_filter('the_content',...........)
```

however, I want that filter only to affect main post's content. See phseudo-example:

```
<html>
.......
<meta decsription>.....the_content...</meta>
.......
<left_widget>....the_content...</left_widget> 
.......
<MAIN_POST>....the_content...</MAIN_POST>         <----------------- I want only this to be affected
......
```

How to achieve? (of course, out-of-question is the category pages, where post_contents are listed)

Answer (score 2):

**This method doesn't work. I leave this answer only as reference.**

If I understand correctly, the easier way is to check if you are in the main query inside the filter's callback:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'cyb_filter_content' );
function cyb_filter_content( $content ) {

    if( is_main_query() ) {

        // Work with $content here

    }

    return $content;

}
```

But this **DOESN'T WORK. Why?**

`is_main_query()` does this:

```
function is_main_query() {
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->is_main_query();
}
```

So, it does not check if the query of the current loop is the main query, it checks if the global `$wp_query` object is the main query; and the global `$wp_query` object **is always the main query** unless it has been modified, which is something, let's say, unusual and often not recommended. So, `is_main_query()` returns `true` almost everywhere and everytime.

Comment: yes, you understand, but that is not complete. because, `is_singular` returns true ,even while outputing content in widget or in `<HEAD>`  `description` meta tag..

Comment: Mmmm ..... Let me check it and think about it.

Comment: Added `is_main_query()`; can you try it and give some feedback?

Comment: hm.. none of the solutions are 100% reliable...  `is_main_query` still returns true while checking from <head> ..

Comment: however, I appreciate your time, and i upvoted you..

Comment: Wo, found solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162787/33667

Comment: Even seeing the [soruce code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3097), It is hard for me to understand why `in_the_loop()` works to check if you are in the main query and `is_main_query()` doesn't when used inside the filter content; both use the global `$wp_query`.

Comment: `is_main_query()` is good candidate for worst named function in core, it does something _absolutely_ different from what you would guess from name — checks if global query had been overridden.

Comment: Answer updated explaning why `is_main_query()` does not work. I will leave the answer as reference.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162787/33667), to use `in_the_loop()` (but read comment below my answer too):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_content' );

function custom_content( $content ) {
    if ( in_the_loop() ) {
        // ....
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: there are all kinds of reasons to do the loop in the head and then rewind it before showing actual content. in_the_loop will just return happily true in the header footer or sidebar. By using it you are trusting theme developers of not doing anything weird.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple, see code below.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ){
    // If it is not page named debug, do nothing
    if( $GLOBALS['post']->post_name != 'debug' )
        return $content;

    // do actions...
    $content = 'my super cool new content';
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: but that uses the static `debug` title. however, thanks for hint. I need the filter for 1000 pages.. I think, `the_title()` may help..

Comment: anything can set the global $post, it is very unreliable indication for anything

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Hooking into `the_content` does not guarantee that we're in the loop.

### Solution

Hook into `pre_get_posts` to exclude certain queries. Hook into the loop via `the_post` before hooking `the_content`.

### Details

Add action to `pre_get_posts` to specifically see if the page is singular.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_106269_pre_get_posts', 10, 1 );
function wpse_106269_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  if( is_singular() ) {
    add_action( 'the_post', 'wpse_106269_the_post', 10, 2 );
  }
}
```

Add an action to `the_post`. This action hook is fired for each post when we're in [`the loop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Once we're in `the_post`, we know that we're in the loop, so we can add a filter to `the_content`.

```
function wpse_106269_the_post( $post, $query ) {
  remove_action( 'the_post', 'wpse_106269_the_post', 10, 2 );    
  add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_106269_the_content', 10, 1 );
}
```

To make sure that `the_content` filter is only fired in `the_post`, remove it so that it doesn't get fired in the future unless it's added again by `the_post` action hook.

```
function wpse_106269_the_content( $content ) {
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_106269_the_content', 10, 1 );
  //* Do something with $content
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: interesting one... however, it doesnt guarantee,that it ahppens only on singular page/post... it will affect Category listings too (where 10 posts are shown).  right?

Comment: it would have. I added a check to see if the page is_singular() which fill now conditionally fire the_post.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an impossible task. `the_content` and its friend `the_excerpt` lack context and it is just impossible to guess the context from looking at the various global variables as they might have been altered.

Some themes provide actions to indicate that they are starting to output the post content but this is far from being standard.

The only way to work with it is to assume other plugin and theme developers are smart and don't use `the_content` for anything which do not actually display the post content. (far fetched assumption)