# How to create bootstrap grid loop?

Tags: loop, twitter-bootstrap

May I know how to create multiple loop for this HTML code in Wordpress?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="normal-video">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div id="video-content-img" style="background-image:url('post-img');">
                    <div class="holder">
                      <div class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                   <p class="category"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> &nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp; 17 Apr 2017</p>
                  <h1><a href="#">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a></h1>
                </div>  
              </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="normal-video">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div id="video-content-img" style="background-image:url('post-img');">
                    <div class="holder">
                      <div class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                   <p class="category"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> &nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp; 17 Apr 2017</p>
                  <h1><a href="#">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a></h1>
                </div>  
              </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="normal-video">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div id="video-content-img" style="background-image:url('post-img');">
                    <div class="holder">
                      <div class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                   <p class="category"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> &nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp; 17 Apr 2017</p>
                  <h1><a href="#">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a></h1>
                </div>  
              </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="normal-video">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div id="video-content-img" style="background-image:url('post-img');">
                    <div class="holder">
                      <div class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                   <p class="category"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> &nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp; 17 Apr 2017</p>
                  <h1><a href="#">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a></h1>
                </div>  
              </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="normal-video">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div id="video-content-img" style="background-image:url('post-img');">
                    <div class="holder">
                      <div class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                   <p class="category"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> &nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp; 17 Apr 2017</p>
                  <h1><a href="#">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a></h1>
                </div>  
              </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="normal-video">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div id="video-content-img" style="background-image:url('post-img');">
                    <div class="holder">
                      <div class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                   <p class="category"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> &nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp; 17 Apr 2017</p>
                  <h1><a href="#">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a></h1>
                </div>  
              </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="normal-video">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div id="video-content-img" style="background-image:url('post-img');">
                    <div class="holder">
                      <div class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                   <p class="category"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> &nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp; 17 Apr 2017</p>
                  <h1><a href="#">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a></h1>
                </div>  
              </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="normal-video">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div id="video-content-img" style="background-image:url('post-img');">
                    <div class="holder">
                      <div class="play-button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                   <p class="category"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> &nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp; 17 Apr 2017</p>
                  <h1><a href="#">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a></h1>
                </div>  
              </div>
</div>
```

And the row keep on going based on the sum of post that we have. Hopefully it will appear like this:
[image]
Please advise. thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mark every 3rd post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/how-to-mark-every-3rd-post)

Answer (score 2):

Okay I got it! And this code works perfectly for me. :)

```
<?php             $args=array(
                 'post_type' => 'post',
                  'posts_per_page' => 4,
                  'paged' => $paged,
                  'tax_query' => array(
                              array(                
                                  'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                  'field' => 'slug',
                                  'terms' => array('post-format-video'),
                                  'operator' => 'IN')
                                  )
                );

              $my_query = null;
              $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

              if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

                $i = 0;
                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
              // modified to work with 3 columns
              // output an open <div>
              if($i % 4 == 0) { ?> 

              <div class="row">

              <?php
              }
              ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'template/loop', 'video' ); ?>
                  <?php $i++; 
                  if($i != 0 && $i % 4 == 0) { ?>
                    </div><!--/.row-->
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                  <?php
                   } ?>

              <?php endwhile; } wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: Ouch but not display well on combination of col-md-4 & col-sm-6. Anyone?